# Connecting to docker machine while connected through VPN in Windows 7

Tags: docker-machine, docker-toolbox

I am running docker-machine on Windows 7 as part of the docker toolbox

When I run

```
> docker-machine env
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=...\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
```

After configuring shell, I can interact with docker without any problem.

The problem arises when I connect to different network through VPN.

When I use

```
> tracert 192.168.99.100
```

I can see this IP is intercepted by VPN and that's the reason I get exception when running

```
> docker-machine env
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating certificates for host "192.168.99.100:2376": dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: i/o timeout
```

Is there a way to change DOCKER_HOST as follows?

```
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2376
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 14):

Start the docker quickstart terminal without connecting to VPN. then follow these steps:

1. docker-machine stop machine-name
2. VBoxManage modifyvm “machine-name” -–natpf1 “machine-name,tcp,,2376,,2376”
3. docker-machine start machine-name

suppose your machine name is default then the command would be : VBoxManage modifyvm “default” -–natpf1 “default,tcp,,2376,,2376”

4. export DOCKER_HOST=”tcp://localhost:2376″
5. export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=”0″
6. alias docker=”docker –-tlsverify=false”

Now connect to VPN. You are good to go. Docker will start working as usual as.

Comment: After a lot of searching on this issue, this answer finally worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a new entry in the routing table that overrides the entry that the VPN software creates.

First, find the name of the VirtualBox Host-Only network interface

```
netsh int ip show ipaddresses
```

On my machine the interface is named "vbox2". Now, specify that all traffic to the docker machine at 192.168.99.100 should be sent through the "vbox2" interface.

```
netsh int ip add route 192.168.99.0/24 interface=vbox2 store=persistent
```

I prefer this method over the 127.0.0.1 solution because I don't have to forward any new ports with VBoxManage modifyvm.

Answer (score 0):

In my Docker terminal:

```
$ docker-machine env
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="XXXXXX\.docker\machine\machines\default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $("D:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env)
```

To override the DOCKER_HOST environment variable:

```
$ export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://127.0.0.1:2376"
```

Refer to [docker-and-cisco-anyconnect-vpn](https://www.iancollington.com/docker-and-cisco-anyconnect-vpn/).This post may help you.